# On the search for an example sentence from a German textbook

Tags: lexical-semantics, german, morphosyntax, examples

Once I read three sentences build of made-up words with correct German declination and conjugation, so you were able to parse this sentence although it beared no semantic meaning. It was something like this:

> Wasanten matusen.
> Tole matust.
> (Ist) Tole Wasant?

Reading this as a German speaker, you won’t understand a word but could derive from the morphemes that:

- *Wasant* is a subject and the singular of *Wasanten.*
- *matusen* is a verb (conjugation is *matuse, matust, matusen).*
- *Tole* is a subject.

So the sentence seems to mean something like

> People or things called *Wasant* do an activity called *matusen.*
>
> A person or thing called *Tole* does also this *matusen* activity.
>
> Is Tole therefore also a Wasant?

Okay, so far I do pretty good remember my example. But I cannot find it again and wonder who came up with it first? And what was the original spelling of the made-up words?

Comment: The third sentence (“Tole wasant?”) does not fully comply with your description as it does at least lack a verb. Assuming that everything else is correct, it would have to be something like: “Ist Tole Wasant?”

Comment: Correct point, thanks. But I do not warrant for those made up words at all as the ones from the original sentece I read my be totally different. :-/